# Android Realm Migration Issue. Field Type change

Tags: android, database, realm

I have certain field in my database class file. I need to change their type from String to int. Which I am doing as per example in github. Below is scenario what I get up ending it

```
public class LeaderBoardDb extends RealmObject {
//    private String percentile;
//
//    private String rank;

    private String details;

    private String email;

    @PrimaryKey
    private String userId;

    private String name;

//    private String rewards;
//
//    private String sweatPointEarned;

    private String photoUrl;

    private String note;

    private String displayName;

    private float userPercentile;

    private int userRank;

    private int userRewards;

    private int userSweatPointsEarned;
}
```

Migration Code

```
if(oldVersion == 6){


                schema.get("LeaderBoardDb")
                        .addField("userPercentile", float.class)
                .addField("userRank",int.class)
                .addField("userRewards",int.class)
                .addField("userSweatPointsEarned", int.class)
                .removeField("percentile")
                .removeField("rank")
                .removeField("rewards")
                .removeField("sweatPointEarned")
                        .renameField("userPercentile", "percentile")
                        .renameField("userRank", "rank")
                        .renameField("userRewards","rewards")
                        .renameField("userSweatPointsEarned", "sweatPointEarned");

                oldVersion++;
            }
```

And Stack Trace what I get is as follows:

```
03-31 13:52:03.901 9535-9535/com.workoutguru.workoutcash E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.workoutguru.workoutcash, PID: 9535
03-31 13:52:03.901 9535-9535/com.workoutguru.workoutcash E/AndroidRuntime: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Primary key not defined for field 'userId' in existing Realm file. Add @PrimaryKey.
03-31 13:52:03.901 9535-9535/com.workoutguru.workoutcash E/AndroidRuntime:     at io.realm.LeaderBoardDbRealmProxy.validateTable(LeaderBoardDbRealmProxy.java:337)
03-31 13:52:03.901 9535-9535/com.workoutguru.workoutcash E/AndroidRuntime:     at io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator.validateTable(DefaultRealmModuleMediator.java:121)
```

Comment: could you also attach previous version of LeaderBoardDb class?

Comment: @IlyaTretyakov The commented fields were in previous version and new fields are added in migration code ( for your ref)

Comment: Did you have PrimaryKey annotation in the previous version?

Comment: @IlyaTretyakov Yes I had the PrimaryKey annotation

Comment: Strange. But try to add these method .addPrimaryKey("userId") - https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmObjectSchema.html#addPrimaryKey-java.lang.String-

Comment: @IlyaTretyakov just Tried doesn't work getting still same crash